Where can I find and iinstall Canon Pixma E414 driver for 24.04.01 system
Installed Ubuntu 24.01.1 but now am unable to print from my Canon Pixma E414 printer scanner. Checked Canon site for new driver etc but informed  this product on Ubuntu system is no longer supported. Can anybody help.
